# set axis limits on individual facets of seaborn facetgrid

Tags: python, facet, seaborn

I'm trying to set the x-axis limits to different values for each facet a Seaborn facetgrid distplot.  I understand that I can get access to all the axes within the subplots through *g.axes*, so I've tried to iterate over them and set the xlim with:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(
    mapping,
    col=options.facetCol,
    row=options.facetRow,
    col_order=sorted(cols),
    hue=options.group,
)
g = g.map(sns.distplot, options.axis)

for i, ax in enumerate(g.axes.flat):  # set every-other axis for testing purposes
    if i % 2 == 0[enter link description here][1]:
        ax.set_xlim(-400, 500)
    else:
        ax.set_xlim(-200, 200)
```

However, when I do this, all axes get set to (-200, 200) not just every other facet.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to pass `False` to `sharey` and `sharex` if you want the axes to have different limits.

Comment: This comment should be the accepted answer ^^

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**mwaskom** had the solution; posting here for completeness - just had to change the following line to:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(
    mapping,
    col=options.facetCol,
    row=options.facetRow,
    col_order=sorted(cols),
    hue=options.group,
    sharex=False,  # <- This option solved the problem!
)
```

Comment: of course mwaskom had the solution... he's the author of seaborn :)

Answer (score 5):

As suggested by [mwaskom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1533576/mwaskom) you can simply use [FacetGrid](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html#seaborn.FacetGrid)'s `sharex` (respectively `sharey`) to allow plots to have independent axis scales:

> **share{x,y} : bool, ‘col’, or ‘row’ optional**
>
> If true, the facets will share y axes across columns and/or x axes across rows.

For example, with:

- `sharex=False` each plot has its own axis
- `sharex='col'` each column has its own axis
- `sharex='row'` each row has its own axis (even if this one doesn't make too much sense to me)

```py
sns.FacetGrid(data, ..., sharex='col')
```

If you use FacetGrid indirectly, for example via [displot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html) or [relplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html#seaborn.relplot), you will have to use the `facet_kws` keyword argument:

```py
sns.displot(data, ..., facet_kws={'sharex': 'col'})
```