# how to set x_axis label(not xtick label) for all subplots in relplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

I tried drawing subplot through `relplot` method of seaborn. Now the question is, due to the original dataset is varying, sometimes I don't know how much final subplots will be.

I set `col_wrap` to limit it, but sometimes the results looks not so good. For example, I set `col_wrap = 3`, while there are 5 subplots as below:

[image]

As the figure shows, the `x_axis` only occurs in the C D E, which seems strange. I want x axis label is shown in all subplots(from A to E).

Now I already know that `facet_kws={'sharex': 'col'}` allows plots to have independent axis scales(according to [set axis limits on individual facets of seaborn facetgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31170480/set-axis-limits-on-individual-facets-of-seaborn-facetgrid?rq=1)).

But I want set labels for x axis of all subplots.I haven't found any solution for it.

Any keyword like `set_xlabels` in object `FacetGrid` seems to be useless, because official document announces they only control "on the bottom row of the grid".

```
FacetGrid.set_xlabels(label=None, clear_inner=True, **kwargs)
Label the x axis on the bottom row of the grid.
```

The following are my example data and my code:

```
  city  date  value
0    A     1      9
1    B     1     20
2    C     1      4
3    D     1     33
4    E     1      2
5    A     2     22
6    B     2     32
7    C     2     27
8    D     2     32
9    E     2     18
```

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel("data/example_data.xlsx")
# print(df)
g = sns.relplot(data=df, x="date", y="value", kind="line", col="city", col_wrap=3,
                    errorbar=None, facet_kws={'sharex': 'col'})
(g.set_axis_labels("x_axis", "y_axis", )
 .set_titles("{col_name}")
 .tight_layout()
 .add_legend()
)

plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.94, wspace=None, hspace=0.4)
plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to reduce superfluous information, Seaborn makes these inner labels invisible.  You can make them visible again:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': np.repeat([1, 2], 5),
                   'value': np.random.randint(1, 20, 10),
                   'city': np.tile([*'abcde'], 2)})
# print(df)
g = sns.relplot(data=df, x="date", y="value", kind="line", col="city", col_wrap=3,
                errorbar=None, facet_kws={'sharex': 'col'})
g.set_titles("{col_name}")
g.add_legend()

for ax in g.axes.flat:
     ax.set_xlabel('x axis', visible=True)
     ax.set_ylabel('y axis', visible=True)

plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.94, wspace=None, hspace=0.4)
plt.show()
```

[image: seaborn facetgrid, adding inner xlabel and ylabel]